# Sound Proofing Window + Storm Window

Tags: sound-proofing, weatherstripping

I have a window which faces a very busy street.

However there are also inserts (storm windows) made out of wood and single pane glass for insertion outside the aluminum half open window (pictured below)

Does anyone have any ideas for products I could use to seal the storm windows to prevent sound transmission.  I don't know if it's legal, but could I seal the windows as well? Could I apply a material to the window to help it seal tight when closed to prevent drafts AND noise.

I ideally would like some kind of sealant I can paste along the aluminum window which would seal against the concrete tightly when I close the window. It could later be scraped or peeled off the aluminum. I have tried weather tape (like puddy) but it falls off the window too easily.

A material to seal in the storm window would probably also help me. Right now that storm window is simply resting in the concrete frame with many gaps present.

Any ideas much appreciated. The pink outside window is the storm window.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at "sound-proof" windows, (I.e.: music rooms, sound studios, etc.), you'll see that the two (or 3) panes of glass are not parallel and not of the same thickness. This helps reflect sound waves back. So, if one wave length passes the first pane, the second pane will be out of sync with that wave length and reflect it back too.

Comment: Hmmm...I should have prefaced my answer by saying I'd start with plugging any openings (like soffit vents, gaps in siding around hose bibbs, windows, etc.), then windows, then walls. Please note that plugging up soffit vents can cause other problems like moisture and dryrot in the attic due to lack of ventilation. Also, permanently sealing bedroom windows up is illegal...you must maintain an "egress" window out of bedrooms.

Comment: Can you add a sentence about where to look for the kind of soundproof windows described?

Comment: @fixer1234 You need to find a window glazer. They make custom windows, frames, etc. and can install the unit. I’d google “window glazer” in your area.

Answer (score 0):

There are clear [films that tape on](http://www.homedepot.com/p/3M-62-in-x-84-in-Clear-Plastic-Indoor-Window-Kit-2120-EP/100353672). I like making a small wood frame that fits snug in the opening and covering the frame with the film (not just taping on the surface but wrapped like a painting canvas with the cut edge of the film to the outside). Once in place a small bead of calking to hold it in place. This would eliminate any drafts and provide another dead airspace to help dampen the noise. Easy to remove and it lets the light in.